# ViewModel Notify Bound ComboBox that List has been changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `ComboBox` bound to a static `List`.

I want to change the items in the List, but the ComboBox will not update to reflect the changes.

---

### XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBox_Items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding cbo_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="100" />
```

---

### C Sharp

**ViewModel Class**

Get/Set ComboBox Items

```
public static List<string> _cbo_Items = new List<string>()
{
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3"
};

public static List<string> ComboBox_Items
{
    get { return _cbo_Items; }
    set { _cbo_Items = value;}
}

public static string cbo_SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

---

**Another Class**

Update the List with new items

```
ViewModel._cbo_Items = new List<string>()
{
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 6"
};
```

---

### Solution

I tried this, it crashes with null exception on `viewModel.OnPropertyChanged("ComboBox_Items")`

```
public static ViewModel viewModel;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public static List<string> ComboBox_Items
{
    get { return _cbo_Items; }
    set { _cbo_Items = value;
          viewModel.OnPropertyChanged("ComboBox_Items");
    }
}
```

Comment: the bind is broken when you 'new' the list, you could use observablecollection and clear and add items instead of create new instance

Comment: @dnr3 I tried this with `ObservableCollection` https://pastebin.com/raw/YVSN7Rvz I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `Add()`.

Comment: can you debug to check which one is null?

Comment: @dnr3 When I `Clear()` the ObservableCollection it makes the ObservableCollection `_cbo_Items` null, then I can't add to it. But if I use List it works. Though it makes my ComboBox items have a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: hmm, I'm sorry, I'm not sure how it happened to you, clearing observablcollection shouldn't have make it null.

Comment: @dnr3 I'm creating a small example project with 2 comboboxes to show you.

Comment: @dnr3 Here is a zipped project. It has `MainWindow.xaml`, `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, `ViewModel.cs`. When you use the first combobox it will crash when changing the item source. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3v0a96n9pjzl3mo/ViewModelTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: I think this is the culprit  SelectedItem="{Binding ComboBox_Items,, change the binding property there, it messed up the vlaue of combobox_items, make teh combobox_items a read only property, yup, I just downloaded your solution, the null issue is because you bind the wrong property on the selecteditem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bind is broken when you 'new' the list, you can use observablecollection and clear then add items instead of creating new instance.

also fix the binding for the combobox's selecteditem property

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBox_Items}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding cbo_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="0,0,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Width="100" />
```

and it will also be better to remove the setter for the ComboBox_Items to prevent it from being re-created.

Comment: I tried it in my example project, it still crashes.

Comment: I just tried on your example and modified the selecteditem binding and it works fine, copy and replace the combobxes with this one https://pastebin.com/bWCcVcFw

Comment: I see, it is working now in the example project. I will test real quick in my main project.